# How can I configure WSO2 APIM not to be able to generate tokens with unlimited lifetimes (-1) for API consumption

Tags: token, wso2-api-manager

I want all APIs to be able to be consumed with a limited lifetime token, clients must regenerate the token when inhaling. Is it possible to guarantee this configuration globally?

I've done several searches but I haven't found any configuration that helps me with this.

Comment: What is the API Manager version?

Comment: API Manager version 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Latest API Manager versions do not allow unlimited lifetime tokens. For the pervious API Manager versions you can add the following configuration to the deployment.toml and change the grant type class.

```
[oauth.grant_type.client_credentials]
enable = true
grant_handler = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.ClientCredentialsGrantHandler"
```

Previous API Manager versions used [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.6.163/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/handlers/ExtendedClientCredentialsGrantHandler.java) extended client credential grant type which supported the validity period explicitly.